# numpy and scipy for preinstalled python 2.6.7 on mac OS Lion

Tags: python, numpy, osx-lion, scipy

Is there anyway to install numpy and scipy on python 2.6.7 that comes with Mac OS Lion? I am aware that Lion has Python 2.7 as well. But I need to stick with Python 2.6 cause I am using a module that does not work on Python 2.7.

Comment: in case you were using Linux just do a symbolic link to what fortran compiler you have and it should do the work. e.g. sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran44 /usr/bin/gfortran

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Lion comes with an [easy_install](https://web.archive.org/web/20130208091204/http://packages.python.org:80/distribute/easy_install.html) for each of its Python implementations: `/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7` for `/usr/bin/python2.7`, and likewise for 2.6 and 2.5.

However, scipy requires a Fortran compiler, and Lion doesn't come with one of those. It also looks like you have to have the Fortran compiler in place before installing numpy, or scipy can't be installed later.

First, you need the Xcode Command Line Tools. (Apple frequently changes the name of this package—it may be "Unix Development Tools", or "CLI Development Toolchain", etc., depending on your Xcode version.)

These can be installed by Xcode itself. If you're using 4.3.x, after installing Xcode from the App Store, launch it, go to Preferences, Downloads, Components, and click the Install button next to "Command Line Tools". For different versions, or if you want to install them without Xcode, the Homebrew page (see below) explains how to get them, or you can look around [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/).

If you've already got a package manager (Homebrew, MacPorts, or Fink), use that. If you don't, install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
curl https://raw.github.com/gist/323731/25f99360c7de3f72027d8fd07cb369b1c8756ea6/install_homebrew.rb -o /tmp/install_homebrew.rb
ruby /tmp/install_homebrew.rb
rehash
```

Then install gfortran like this:

```
brew install gfortran
```

Now you're ready to install numpy and scipy. If you prefer [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) to easy_install (if you don't know, you probably prefer pip), you have to install that first:

```
sudo easy_install-2.6 pip
```

Then use it to install the packages:

```
sudo pip-2.6 install numpy
```

Depending on your exact OS version and other details, you may already have a built-in numpy for 2.6, but that numpy doesn't have Fortran support. You can tell this because `sudo pip-2.6 install numpy` says `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`. The solution is to do exactly what the error message says:

```
sudo pip-2.6 install --upgrade numpy
```

And finally:

```
sudo pip-2.6 install scipy
```

Comment: Hi @abarnet. I really appreciate if you see my comment on installation problem

Comment: Unfortunately, the most accessible clean Lion test box has recently become a clean Mountain Lion test box, so I'm not sure I'll be able to try to reproduce anything until next week. But one thing you might want to try (not because it'll solve your problem, but to help diagnose it): Run python2.6, then `import numpy` and `import numpy.f2py` and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Hi @abarnert,  Thanks a lot  Here is a copy of the error again: after following the described steps, I got the following error: Setup script exited with error: can't 
copy         '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/
Extras/lib/python/numpy/f2py/src/for  tranobject.h': doesn't exist or 
not a regular file
I ran Python 2.6, and tried import numpy  and import bumpy.f2py and I ran it but didn't get any error! I really appreciate any help/comment.

Comment: What order did you do the installs in? From a quick test, it looks like if you install numpy before gfortran, you don't get fortranobject.c/h, which means when you try to build scipy, it gets exactly the error you mentioned. I'll edit the answer to show the ordering, in hopes that this is your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @abarnert; I followed the steps and this is what I got: first I got    UserWarning: UMFPACK sparse solver (http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/) not found.  and after a while I got error: can't copy '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h': doesn't exist or not a regular file
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Running from scipy source directory.  then I got similar error with 
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/nasernikandish/build/scipy  at the end

Comment: Just as a side note, does it have anything to do with installing scipy on preinstalled python 2.6 on Mac? As I mentioned earlier, I have to stick with preinstalled Python 2.6; but in scipy's website it says: you should use python downloaded from python.org's website.

Comment: If I may interject, I am not sure exactly why, but I ran into the same problem installing numpy and scipy on my mac. They are not 100% compatible with the Apple version of Python. Look into the enthought python distribution. It installs a version of python with numpy and scipy with it.

Comment: @Abarnert: I forgot to mention that for the second time I followed the sequence you suggested.

Comment: @Nino: I have to stay with Python 2.6 that comes with Mac Lion.

Comment: @Nino: Apple did ship deficient Python builds with either Tiger or Leopard a few years ago, but there's nothing wrong with Lion's 2.6 and 2.7. I just took a clean Lion machine, followed exactly the steps I listed above for Apple's 2.6 and 2.7, and got a working scipy on each. And on a clean Mountain Lion machine, I did the same, and again it worked.

Comment: My guess is that you had stuff left over from your broken first attempt. In particular, if you installed numpy, failed to install scipy, then did "brew install gfortran; pip install numpy; pip install scipy", that won't cause numpy to get re-built (with working fortran support) and replaced. You may be able to just "pip uninstall numpy" and try again, but I won't promise that'll fix everything.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks a lot for all your help. this is what I did:  Installed a clean OS Lion, Installed all the updates, installed Homebrew, installed Xcode, installed gfortran; when I tried to install numpy I got a message saying    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
Cleaning up...   then I tried  installing spicy and got the following message:

Comment: error: can't copy '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h': doesn't exist or not a regular file

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/nasernikandish/build/scipy
Storing complete log in /Users/nasernikandish/Library/Logs/pip.log      Am I doing something wrong? I can install another clean copy of OS. It is not a big deal; but I am just so confused. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't think matters; but I installed Xcode from app store. It is fine; right? (I know it might be a very silly question); I am just trying to figure out the problem!

Comment: You have to install a numpy with gfortran support. When you tried, it told you "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)". Did you use --upgrade to upgrade? If not, you obviously still have the numpy that came with Lion's 2.6, which doesn't have gfortran support.

Comment: @ abarnert: THanks a million for your help and patience. I tried           sudo pip-2.6 install --upgrade numpy  and I got some errors at the beginning like:
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable xlf90
    Could not locate executable xlf
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
 And at the end I got:

Comment: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy
Storing complete log in /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Logs/pip.log
  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The "could not locate…" things are normal. It checks for every fortran compiler it knows how to use, and as long as it successfully finds one, everything is fine. As for the error at the end, I can't really help without seeing the complete log. Maybe create a new question about building numpy for Lion Python 2.6 with gfortran support, posting the exact steps you took and the failing log, instead of adding to the comments here.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks a million for your help and patience :) I installed command line tools and it worked like a charm! So for the future reference, all the steps mentioned by user abarnert are correct. Just add the following step:  After installing Xcode, go to Xcode preferences, downloads, under components tab, install command line tools. Thanks a lot! I thought installing Xcode automatically installs command line tools.

Answer (score 24):

I was running into similar issues installing SciPy on Mountain Lion.

OSX Mountain Lion 10.8

Python 2.7.3

pip 1.1

brew 0.9.2

GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.2.1

Some of the errors I was receiving include:

This:

```
pip install scipy
```

Yielded this error:

```
Could not locate executable pgfortran

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

building 'dfftpack' library

error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

Which led me to look for a Fortran compiler:

This command:

```
brew install gfortran
```

Which yielded this error:

```
Error: Currently the gfortran compiler provided by this brew is only supports the following versions of XCode:

    - XCode 3.1.4 on OS X 10.5.x
    - XCode 3.2.2/3.2.3 -- 4.0 on OS X 10.6.x
    - XCode 4.1 or newer on OS X 10.7.x

The AppStore and Software Update can help upgrade your copy of XCode.
The latest version of XCode is also available from:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html
```

Which led me to a blog post: http://www.joewandy.com/. I followed this recommendation:

This command:

```
brew edit gfortran
```

will open a file using xcode. I modified this file in exactly two places:

Theses 2 lines:

```
if MacOS.xcode_version >= '4.2' and MACOS_VERSION == 10.7
    ohai "Installing gfortran 4.2.4 for XCode 4.2 (build 5666)"
```

Changed to:

```
if MacOS.xcode_version >= '4.2' and MACOS_VERSION >= 10.7
    ohai "Installing gfortran 4.2.4 for XCode 4.2 (build 5666) or higher"
```

in other words:

Changed `== 10.7` to `>= 10.7`
and
Changed `XCode 4.2 (build 5666)` to `XCode 4.2 (build 5666) or higher`

Then I did

```
brew install gfortran
```

again. which was successful with a message of:

```
Downloading http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg

Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gfortran-4.2.4-5666.3.pkg
==> Installing gfortran 4.2.4 for XCode 4.2 (build 5666) or higher
==> Caveats
Brews that require a Fortran compiler should not use:

depends_on 'gfortran'

The preferred method of declaring Fortran support is to use:

def install
    ...
    ENV.fortran
    ...
end

==> Summary

/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.2.4-5666.3: 86 files, 72M, built in 2 seconds
```

Then I did:

```
pip install scipy
```

but that gave me this:

```
#error "<vecLib/vecLib.h> is deprecated.  Please #include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h> and link to Accelerate.framework."
```

Then I found this blog post: 
Compiling SciPy on Mountain Lion
http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2012/compiling-scipy-on-mountain-lion/

which said to use this command:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy#egg=scipy-dev
```

This took about 5 to 6 minutes to complete

```
Installed /Users/hernamesbarbara/src/scipy
Successfully installed scipy
Cleaning up...
```

after which I could do

```
python


Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> help(scipy)

    Help on package scipy:

NAME
    scipy
```

Success!

SciPy version installed:

```
full_version = '0.12.0.dev-14b1e07'
git_revision = '14b1e07602ff33a6e8250eb2bc7a6816677606a9'
release = False
short_version = '0.12.0'
version = '0.12.0.dev-14b1e07'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to install Brew and XCode, nor compile gfortran yourself: I installed a compiled version of gfortran from http://hpc.sourceforge.net and everything seems to be working. (I am on 10.7.5)

Comment: Well pre-compiled binary will work, but I think `brew` is just cool.