# Building numpy for Lion Python 2.6 with gfortran support

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gfortran

I am trying to install numpy and scipy on preinstalled Python 2.6 that comes with Lion OS.

Here is the exact steps I am taking:

- install a clean copy of

  - Lion,
  - updates,
  - Xcode (from app store),
  - Homebrew,
  - gfortran,
  - pip,
  - and numpy.
- Next step is trying to upgrade numpy. 
  Here is what happens: (I couldn't post the full log because I am a limited user.

```
Downloading/unpacking numpy from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-    1.6.2.zip#md5=7e13c931985f90efcfa0408f845d6fee
```

Downloading numpy-1.6.2.zip (2.9Mb): 2.9Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
Running from numpy source directory.non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-    I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']

lapack_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']

build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
customize NAGFCompiler
Could not locate executable f95
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
customize IBMFCompiler
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
C compiler: llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-    common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -    Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -    DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -    Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -    Inumpy/core/include -    I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c'
llvm-gcc-4.2: _configtest.c
sh: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found
sh: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/setup.py", line 207, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py",     line 152, in setup
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py",     line 975, in run_commands
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 8, in     run
    self.run_command("build_src")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py",     line 995, in run_command
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 163, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 298, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 696, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Running from numpy source directory.non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

FOUND:

extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]

extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']



lapack_opt_info:

FOUND:

extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]

extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']



running egg_info

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.6

creating build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.6/numpy

creating build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.6/numpy/distutils

building library "npymath" sources

customize NAGFCompiler

Could not locate executable f95

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

Could not locate executable f77

customize IBMFCompiler

Could not locate executable xlf90

Could not locate executable xlf

customize IntelFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifc

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran

customize Gnu95FCompiler

customize Gnu95FCompiler using config

C compiler: llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c'

llvm-gcc-4.2: _configtest.c

sh: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found

sh: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/setup.py", line 214, in <module>

setup_package()

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/setup.py", line 207, in setup_package

configuration=configuration )

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup

return old_setup(**new_attr)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 8, in run

self.run_command("build_src")

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run

self.build_sources()

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 163, in build_sources

self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 298, in build_library_sources

sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources

source = func(extension, build_dir)

File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 696, in get_mathlib_info

raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in     /Users/MYUSERNAME/build/numpy
Storing complete log in /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Logs/pip.log

I really appreciate any help/comment/guidance.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks a lot for your help. Please let me know if there is a way for me (limited user) to post the full log. I got an error saying I need more reputation to send long questions. If necessary, I may upload it to a website or something. Cheers

Comment: You'd be better off posting into a pastebin (or equiv.) the code, and summarising the points of interest for your question. The SO format likes a specific point, not a huge dump of data... Take this as a constructive criticism please :) Then people with enough rep. can edit your question, or comments can be made that require you to pick bits out and amend your question... quid pro quo... - then, hopefully you get an answer, and it's archived with all relevant points to help someone else out later...

Comment: Did you install command line tools from Xcode?

Comment: @tabchas: Thanks a million for your comment. I installed command line tools and it worked like a charm! So for the future reference, all the steps mentioned in the questions are correct. Just add the following step:  After installing Xcode, go to Xcode preferences, downloads, under components tab, install command line tools. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Here is a complete solution provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442970/numpy-and-scipy-for-preinstalled-python-2-6-7-on-mac-os-lion

Comment: Hey no problem... I had the same issue some time ago when I purchased my Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the official installation instructions ?

http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X

Comment: Official installation works only for Pythons downloaded from python.org