# numpy and scipy for preinstalled python 2.7.1 on mac OS Lion

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pip

I am trying to install numpy and scipy for python 2.7.1 that comes with Mac OS Lion. I tried to follow instructions on [numpy and scipy for preinstalled python 2.6.7 on mac OS Lion 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442970/numpy-and-scipy-for-preinstalled-python-2-6-7-on-mac-os-lion). fter installing gfortran, `sudo easy_install-2.7 pip`works just fine. But when I try `sudo pip2.7 install numpy`, I get the following error

`Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Logs/pip.log`

I remember when I was trying to install it for Python 2.6, I did not have this problem. Any suggestion for resolving this problem?

Comment: have you tried `sudo pip2.7 install setuptools`?

Comment: @MattDMo: I tried and got exactly the same error.

Comment: have you tried installing setuptools and pip via [this method](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)? Your existing version of `easy_install` may not be installing the correct version.

Comment: Easiest to get the precompiled versions with Anaconda: http://continuum.io/downloads

Comment: @MrE: I need Gurobi optimization solver which requires using the Python that comes with Mac.